# How to add case record type in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to add case record type to the below VF page?

Steps Taken:

1.Standard Opportunity page layout has the case record type on the related list.

2.Profiles permissions for Case Object are good.

3.Profile  permissions for the Case record type field are good.

4.Profile  permissions for the record type are good.

Below is the code. But still unable to see the record type in the related list on the VF page. Any thoughts on how to add are much appreciated.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity"> 
    <apex:relatedList list="Contracts__r" />
    <apex:relatedList list="Cases__r" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you set permissions for the Visualforce Page?

Comment: Did you set permissions by adding it to profile in Settings  Visualforce Page? And mark it for use in:  Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app